# Python taking too much of memory

Tags: python, numpy, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am importing sparse matrices from .npz file. Below is the script of the code. The sparse matrices (Dx, Dy, ..., M) have 373248x373248 size with 746496 stored elements.

```
if runmode == 2:
        data = np.load('Operators2.npz', allow_pickle=True)

    Dx = data['Dx']
    Dy = data['Dy']
    Dz = data['Dz']
    Dxx = data['Dxx']
    Dyy = data['Dyy']
    Dzz = data['Dzz']
    Dxp = data['Dxp']
    Dyp = data['Dyp']
    Dzp = data['Dzp']
    M = data['M']
    del data
```

If I print one of the variable, for example Dx, I get below output:

```
array(<373248x373248 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 746496 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>,
      dtype=object)
```

But my system memory goes up and the program crashes. The program crashes when I execute the below line of code. I do not get any error, but the program crashes.

```
DIV = Dx*u+Dy*v+Dz*w
```

Even if I execute below lines of code, the memory consumption goes up and the program crashes

```
DIV = data['Dx']*u+data['Dy']*v+data['Dz']*w
```

Here u,v,w has 373248x1 shape. The shape of DIV is 373248x1. Since Dx, Dy, Dz are sparse matrices, Dx*u does matrix-vector multiplication and gives a vector.

If in the same code, I actually compute Dx, Dy,...,M there is no problem with the memory. If I am computing Dx then the output is as below:

```
<373248x373248 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 746496 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

So I think the issue with creating an object while importing. Is there a way to avoid that? Or,am I doing something wrong while importing the sparse matrices? 
Thank you.

Comment: Why copy each column from data to a new object? This doubles the memory footprint, assuming you are copying all columns in data. Is there a reason you cannot work with the columns while leaving them in data?

Comment: But, I am deleting data once all variables (Dx, Dy, ...,M) are assigned. So the memory should get releases. Also, I found that the memory goes up when I run 'DIV = Dx*u +Dy*v + Dz*w' command. u,v,w are 373248x1 vector.

Comment: @Ethan, `data` from loading a `npz` is a dictionary like object.  The arrays are only loaded when accessed via `Dy=data['Dy']` expressions.  So there's not doubling.  The `del data` line also isn't needed, since the memory use of the dictionary is minimal.

Comment: Could you edit the question to clearly show the `type`, `dtype` and `shape` of all variables.  Some that data is present, but scattered and hard to put together.  What shape (etc) do you expect for `DIV`?  Can you do the `Dx*u` etc calculations individually?

Comment: Do you get a traceback with the memory error?  That could help identify exactly were the error is occurring.   Does it help if you calculate `DIV` before loading all the `Dxx` etc?  You calculate `Dx` etc?  when/where?  In another session?  Do you also try to calculate `DIV` then?

Comment: The bottom line is that, if you accumulate enough large arrays in memory, even if they are temporary ones in a calculation, you will hit a memory error.  There's no magical memory management trick.

Comment: I think the issue is with the object creation. I was using np.savz() to store variables. If I use scipy.sparse.save_npz(), there will not be a problem with the object creation. Is there a way to store multiple variables with scipy.sparse.save_npz()?

Comment: indexing a numpy array usually does not create a copy, but rather a view. This allows array operations to be done efficiently without copying huge amounts of data. (eg. `b = a[0::2] + a[1::2]`only creates one new array [as opposed to three]) However, this means the view must keep the original array in memory even if the original array has been "deleted". Thus `M` will keep alive the block of memory referenced by `data` (if it is a numpy array). If you only need to keep part of data, use something like `data['M'].copy()`.

Comment: @Dunes, turns out the problem is with the object wrapper that `np.savez` adds when saving a sparse matrix.  The reloaded array cannot be used directly in calculations.  I had to experiment with an actual test matrix to see this.

Comment: @hpaulj. I beg to differ. When you load the file the data is brought into memory. data._sizeof__() will show how many bytes used immediately after loading.

Comment: With a `npz` file, `data` is a directory.  `data['M']` loads an array.  But measuring the size is tricky if the dtype is `object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a sparse matrix:

```
In [38]: M = sparse.random(1000,1000,.2,'csr')
```

save it 3 different ways:

```
In [39]: from scipy import io                                                                  
In [40]: np.savez('Msparse.npz', M=M)                                                          
In [41]: sparse.save_npz('M1sparse',M)                                                         

In [43]: io.savemat('Msparse.mat', {'M':M})
```

file sizes:

```
In [47]: ll M1spa* Mspar*                                                                      
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul 1773523 Feb  1 12:40 M1sparse.npz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul 2404208 Feb  1 12:41 Msparse.mat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul 2404801 Feb  1 12:39 Msparse.npz
```

Load the 3 matrices:

```
In [48]: M1=sparse.load_npz('M1sparse.npz')                                                    
In [49]: M2=np.load('Msparse.npz',allow_pickle=True)['M']                                      
In [50]: M3=io.loadmat('Msparse.mat')['M']                                                     
In [51]: M1                                                                                    
Out[51]: 
<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 200000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [52]: M2                                                                                    
Out[52]: 
array(<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 200000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
      dtype=object)
In [53]: M3                                                                                    
Out[53]: 
<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 200000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

`M1` and `M3` are the same - `csr` like `M` for `save_npz`, `csc` (the MATLAB format) for `.mat`.

`M2` is has an object dtype wrapper.

```
In [54]: (M1*np.ones((1000,1))).shape                                                          
Out[54]: (1000, 1)
In [55]: (M3*np.ones((1000,1))).shape                                                          
Out[55]: (1000, 1)
```

This took a lot longer; and I almost don't dare look at the result.

```
In [56]: (M2*np.ones((1000,1))).shape                                                          
Out[56]: (1000, 1)
```

If I extract the matrix from the object array, the multiplication is fast

```
In [57]: (M2.item()*np.ones((1000,1))).shape                                                   
Out[57]: (1000, 1)
In [58]: (M2.item()*np.ones((1000,1))).dtype                                                   
Out[58]: dtype('float64')
In [59]: (M3*np.ones((1000,1))).dtype                                                          
Out[59]: dtype('float64')
```

Looking more closely at the `M2` multiplication:

```
In [60]: (M2*np.ones((1000,1))).dtype                                                          
Out[60]: dtype('O')
In [61]: (M2*np.ones((1000,1)))[:2,:]                                                          
Out[61]: 
array([[<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 200000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>],
       [<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 200000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]],
      dtype=object)
```

It's performing a `M*1` multiplication for each element of `ones` - making 1000 sparse matrices.  That's where your memory consumption is going.

In sum, when using `savez` it wraps each sparse matrix in an object dtype array, and does the pickle.  So you shouldn't use `data['Dx'] directly

```
Dx = data['Dx']  # wrong
Dx = data['Dx'].item()    # right
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by using [scipy.io.savemat()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html) and [scipy.io.loadmat()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html). I was using np.savz() and np.load() before and that was taking too much memory.

Comment: There's also a `sparse.save_npz` function.  But with `savez` are the reloaded matrices the same type and dimensions as original?  `save_npz` uses the `savez` to save the relevant attributes of the sparse matrix.  So it produces one zip archive for each matrix.

Comment: But I cannot save multiple matrices with ```sparse.save_npz```. It is only for one matrix.

Comment: You can save each matrix separately.  Doing that in a loop isn't **that** hard!  It's almost more work making the dictionary that you pass to `savemat`.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation would be well-suited for in-place operations:

```
np.multiply(data['Dx'], u, out=data['Dx']
np.multiply(data['Dy'], v, out=data['Dy']
np.multiply(data['Dz'], w, out=data['Dz']
numpy.add(data['Dx'], data['Dy'], out=data['Dx'])
numpy.add(data['Dx'], data['Dz'], out=data['Dx'])
```

which creates no additional temporary arrays. If you also avoid loading the other variables that are not required for this specific computation, you will save additional memory. Doing the work inside a function is a good way to ensure you clean-up / free memory once the work is done. In your case it is possibly better to pay a read penalty and just read in the specific data you need for each such calculation. Though like hpaulj said, there's not much more magic you can find; it's a large dataset and will require lots of memory. Any way to reduce the size / resolution of the problem, or work it in smaller blocks?